# How to prove an expression is positive over range

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality

I have run into an issue where I need to prove that the following is weakly positive where $n\geq3$ and is an integer and $a\geq1$
$$(a(n-1)-1)(a+1)-\Bigg(a^2(n-1)^2-1-a\Bigg)(\frac{a}{a+1})^{a(n-1)}$$
This expression goes to infinity when either $n$ or $a$ go to infinity as the rightmost fraction goes to 0. But I am at a loss for how to prove this. I tried to show the derivative wrt to n is always positive but didn't manage to do so.

Comment: A quite complicated expression !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
\begin{align*}
 &[a(n-1)-1](a+1)- [a^2(n-1)^2-1-a]\left(\frac{a}{a+1}\right)^{a(n-1)}\\
 \ge{}& [a(n-1)-1](a+1)-[a^2(n-1)^2-1]\left(\frac{a}{a+1}\right)^{a(n-1)}\\
 ={}& [a(n-1) - 1]\left(a + 1 - [a(n-1) + 1] \left(\frac{a}{a+1}\right)^{a(n-1)}\right)\\
 \ge{}& [a(n-1) - 1]\left(a + 1 - [a(n-1) + (n-1)] \left(\frac{a}{a+1}\right)^{a(n-1)}\right)\\
 ={}& [a(n-1) - 1](a + 1)\left(1 - (n-1) \left(\frac{a}{a+1}\right)^{a(n-1)}\right)\\
 \ge{}& [a(n-1) - 1](a + 1)\left(1 - (n-1) \left(\frac12\right)^{n-1}\right)\\
 ={}& [a(n-1) - 1](a + 1)\left(\frac12\right)^{n-1}\left(2^{n-1} - (n-1) \right)\\
 >{}& 0
\end{align*}
where we use $\left(\frac{a}{a+1}\right)^{a} \le \frac12$ (that is $(1 + 1/a)^a \ge 2$),
and $2^{n-1} - (n - 1) > 0$ (easy).